# Jquery css returning Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery

```
$(".dot")
   .toArray()[Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1)]
   .css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Do you see a problem? It's driving me crazy trying to find it!

ERROR: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your approach is that you need to convert the final result into a jquery object because it is a dom element.

`$( $(".dot").toArray()[Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1)] ).css(...)`